# How to read a file in Flutter server side

Tags: flutter, dart, web, io

I've looked up many topic but none seems to do what i need.

I am working on a website with flutter and i need to read a file thats located on the server.
Is this in any way possible?

Edit: The contents in this file change, so i have to update the contents on the website.

Comment: You'll first have to fetch it somehow and send it to your app

Comment: maybe i missunderstand something. The website is allready located on a webserver, right? so isn't there any way to read a local file on the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access the file as if it was locally stored, then it needs to be registered under your assets in your pubspec.yaml & should be included in the project itself. Otherwise, you will have to fetch the file using something like [DIO](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) to fetch it from wherever it is hosted.

Comment: Thank you, that was a nice idea. 
Well, but i have to update the file with new data which should be regulary updated on screen, but the content will only be seen after a full reload of the website :(. I think i'll go with receiving the contents with a HTTP client.